# Pure flexbox grid with repeating irregular pattern

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a responsive grid using only Flexbox.
The grid is irregular with most fields taking up 25% of the screen and every 3rd and 9th item taking up 50%. A complete grid, therefore, contains 14 items, before the pattern restarts.

My code so far looks like this:

```
<ul class="grid-container">
  <li class="grid-item">1</li>
  <li class="grid-item">2</li>
  <li class="grid-item">3</li>
  <li class="grid-item">4</li>
  <li class="grid-item">5</li>
  <li class="grid-item">6</li>
  <li class="grid-item">7</li>
  <li class="grid-item">8</li>
  <li class="grid-item">9</li>
  <li class="grid-item">10</li>
  <li class="grid-item">11</li>
  <li class="grid-item">12</li>
  <li class="grid-item">13</li>
  <li class="grid-item">14</li>
  <li class="grid-item">15</li>
  <li class="grid-item">16</li>
  <li class="grid-item">17</li>
  <li class="grid-item">18</li>
  <li class="grid-item">19</li>
  <li class="grid-item">20</li>
  <li class="grid-item">21</li>
  <li class="grid-item">22</li>
  <li class="grid-item">23</li>
  <li class="grid-item">24</li>
  <li class="grid-item">25</li>
  <li class="grid-item">26</li>
  <li class="grid-item">27</li>
  <li class="grid-item">28</li>
</ul>
```

SASS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 14.0625vw;
  min-width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 0.5rem solid white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  &:nth-of-type(3), &:nth-of-type(9) {
    min-width: 50%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    height: 28.125vw;
    min-width: 50%;
    &:nth-of-type(3n) {
      min-width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    height: 56.25vw;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

See it in action: https://codepen.io/jakeherp/pen/OGvjJe

How can I make this pattern repeat itself?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: if it's because you use the wrong `nth-child` - you want `14n+3` and `14n+9` (if there are 14 items and you only want the third and ninth to be 50%)

Comment: Sorry, added the question! Posted this too quickly.
Pete has given the solution though! I tried `3n + 14`, but `14n + 3` works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as @Pete said for *repeating child patterns* you can use [Functional notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Functional_notation):

> `<An+B>`
>   Represents elements whose numeric position in a series of
>   siblings matches the pattern An+B, for every positive integer or zero
>   value of n. The index of the first element is 1, and n  in the formula
>   starts counting in 0. The values A and B must both be <integer>s.

It works with both [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) and [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

So instead of `&:nth-of-type(3), &:nth-of-type(9)` you should try:

```
&:nth-of-type(14n+3), &:nth-of-type(14n+9) {
  min-width: 50%;
}
```